# TerminateProcess with GetCurrentProcess() handle and with GetCurrentProcessId() handle

Tags: c, windows, winapi, undocumented-behavior, nt-native-api

I'm studying Windows Internals. In fact, there's no similar `_exit` system call like in *nix.

The process should terminate itself with `TerminateProcess`/`NtTerminateProcess`.

`ExitProcess`/`RtlExitUserProcess` API doing some cleanup before self-terminate.

---

`TerminateProcess`/`NtTerminateProcess` work with `GetCurrentProcess`/`NtCurrentProcess`/`(HANDLE)-1`.

But when I try it with `GetCurrentProcessId`/`gs:[0x40]` it didn't work.

```c
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0); // work
    TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcessId(), 0); // didn't work
}
```

```
mov rcx, -1
xor edx, edx
call TerminateProcess
; this one is working
call GetCurrentProcessId
mov ecx, eax
xor edx, edx
call TerminateProcess
; this one didn't work
```

---

Why Windows processes must self terminate itself with `GetCurrentProcess` and can't work with `GetCurrentProcessId` ?

Comment: Please show the code you tried

Comment: Because TerminateProcess takes a HANDLE as the first argument, GetCurrentProcessId returns a DWORD?

Comment: Why would TerminateProcess work with the process id?

Comment: Also because you have tagged this with `undocumented-behavior`, you can find the documentation for TerminateProcess [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess). You can also find all windows api documentation if you search `FunctionName msvc` into google.

Comment: @Ex-Kyuto "*In fact, there's no similar _exit system call like in nix*" - not in the Win32 API, no. But the C and C++ runtime libraries do define their own standard `(std::)exit()` (cleanup) and `(std::)abort()` (no cleanup) functions. Use those instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for `TerminateProcess()` clearly says that it takes a process **handle**, whereas `GetCurrentProcessID()` returns a process **ID** instead. Why would you expect that ID to work?

One comment of yours seems to suggest that you think a process HANDLE is the same as a process ID. Clearly that is not true, otherwise `GetCurrentProcess()` *and* `GetCurrentProcessID()` would not exist as separate APIs.

In fact, `GetCurrentProcess()` actually returns `0xffffffff`.

The docs say:

> The return value is a pseudo handle to the current process.

Comment: Nvm, that's clearly my falls. I should take the self process handle from OpenProcess and not current process id.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, like the other said, `TerminateProcess` accept process handle, and not process id.

I should take the handle from `OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, false, GetCurrentProcessId())`.

Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: "*I should take the handle from OpenProcess()*" - no, you should use `GetCurrentProcess()` instead. There is no need to open a *real* handle to the calling process, when the *pseudo* handle to the calling process will suffice.